# Use ContentEditable to Save Into DB With ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a web page where a user can edit the text and when they are done, they hit save and the new text entered is saved into the database.

I'm not getting any errors in my code, but for some reason, the old text is just being rewritten into the db instead of the new text.

Here is my code-behind:

```
protected void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newName;
    string newIntro;
    string newEduc;
    string newWork;

    h1New.Text = h1.Text;

    newName = h1New.Text;
    newIntro = intro.Text;
    newEduc = educ.Text;
    newWork = employ.Text;

    string connectionInfo = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionInfo))
    {

        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE simpleContent SET userName = @newName, infoContent = @newIntro, educContent = @newEduc, workContent = @newWork WHERE userID = @userName", connection);

        try
        {

            string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", username.ToString());
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newName", newName.ToString());
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newIntro", newIntro.ToString());
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newEduc", newEduc.ToString());
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newWork", newWork.ToString());
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://www.google.co.uk");
        }


    }
}
```

I would appreciate any pointers that you may have.

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have in your 'Page_Load' method?

Answer (score 0):

try to put you code in format:

```
protected void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
// add variables
     string connectionInfo = (...)
     string commandText = (...)

    using (...){
        SqlCommand myCommand = (...)
        // add parameters

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
            {
                (...)
            }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I got the same result.  The page simply reloads and the values in the db are still the same.

Comment: you connection string are correct?? try debug your code and see the value of the variables to see where the code didn't do what it should.